# How to insert working TAB char on Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, tabs, messagebox, delphi-xe3

I use the following to show a messagebox where I would like some info to be alligned using a TAB char.
This is working OK on Windows XP but not on Windows 7 (I have no Windows 8 to test).

```
      ShowMessage(lSearch + sLineBreak +
                  'Breddegrad:  ' + Chr(9) + HAMInfo.Latitude + sLineBreak +
                  'Længdegrad:  ' + Chr(9) + HAMInfo.Longitude + sLineBreak +
                  'QRA locator: ' + Chr(9) + HAMInfo.Qra);
```

What other options are there if this can't be fixed to work on Windows 7?

Delphi XE3

Comment: I always prefer the real Windows API `MessageBox` to `ShowMessage`. Hint: `#9` is neater than `Chr(9)`. Using `#` you can also omit the `+` operator next to string *literals*.

Comment: What do you expect the tab character to do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan probably just like with console - add spaces until next mod-8 position. Which anyway would give him proper alignment due to default fonts being proportional.

Comment: Like Andreas suggests, [`you may use`](http://pastebin.com/vwJmybxt) the native `MessageBox` function.

Comment: I would like the Latitude, Longitude and Qra to be aligned at a tabstop 
It would be nicer to look at I think
What I think is strange is that on Windows XP the TABs are there but on Windows 7 they are not.

Comment: That's because of internally called [`TaskDialogIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which doesn't seem to care about TABs.

Answer (score 1):

The other variant is using `ShowMessageFmt` or using `format` function explicitly before calling `ShowMessage`.

But due to default fonts being proportional rather than fixed-width, it would still not result in a fine equal alignment.

- http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ShowMessageFmt
- http://delphi.about.com/library/rtl/blrtlShowMessageFmt.htm

.

```
 ShowMessageFmt('%s'#13#10 + 
   '%-16s%s'#13#10 + '%-16s%s'#13#10 + '%-16s%s',
   [ lSearch , 'Breddegrad:', HAMInfo.Latitude, 
               'Længdegrad:', HAMInfo.Longitude,
               'QRA locator:', HAMInfo.Qra ] );
```

Comment: I will have to give this a go tomorrow

Comment: @Arioch, this doesn't help. If you're on Windows 7 and the `UseLatestCommonDialogs` variable is True, then the `TaskDialogIndirect` function is internally called. And this function seems to ignore TABs.

Comment: @TLama 1) and if to set it false before call ? that might be an alternative and also correct answer! 2) where do i use TABs ?

Comment: @TLama, i little typo, if i understand you. And really, you should make an alternative answer!

Comment: Why should @TLama write an answer? Do you mean that in order to be eligible to comment on an answer, you should also write an answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because SO is QA site and it is goal is to keep as many correct answers as possible. Since TLama came with a correct answer already it is a proper thing to not bury it inside comments but to explicitly publish it for both topicstarter and all future readers

Comment: @Arioch 'The   I would say that your suggestion to use ShowMessageFmt improved the quality of the message by at least 50% - it could be better but for now it is OK

Comment: @OZ8HP well, if you need grid-like data you better to make your own class to display grid messages. Maybe starting with mORMot task dialogs implementation for basis. Or you may try TLama's suggestion and hope it would work. But since i don't think that MSDN alert dialogs had specified tab stop consistent support - you are not to expect this solution reliable and future-proof.

Comment: @Arioch 'The - I might have to make a for with a grid of some kind some time in the future.